# jQuery UI Tooltip: Close on click on tooltip itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have a page with a jQuery UI tooltip that is initially opened and its closing on `mouseout` event is disabled.

Now, I want the tooltip to close after a user clicks on it itself, not on the element for which the tooltip is shown (as many other answers here).

As one of the possible solutions, I thought I can add a `click` handler to the tooltip's div and close it from there. But I can't find a standard way to obtain the tooltip's div with the Tooltip widget API or attach the handler in some other way.

Am I on the right track with the approach above? Or how to achieve what I am after in a different way?

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexandrAbakumov/77s3mn3t/1/#&togetherjs=tbhGM5r4aT)** illustrating what I have for the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a relatively simple solution without hacking the Tooltip API via attaching a `click` handler in the tooltip's `open` event and closing the tooltip there:

```
$('.first')
    .tooltip({
         content: 'Click to close',
         position: { my: 'left center', at: 'right center' },
         items: '*'

         open: function (event, ui) {
             var $element = $(event.target);
             ui.tooltip.click(function () {
                 $element.tooltip('close');
             });
         },
    })
    .tooltip('open')
    .on('mouseout focusout', function(event) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexandrAbakumov/77s3mn3t/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.first')
        .tooltip({ content: 'Click to close', position: { my: 'left center', at: 'right center' }, items: '*' })
        .tooltip('open')
        .on('mouseout focusout', function(event) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        })

        // when the tooltip opens (you could also use 'tooltipcreate'), grab some properties and bind a 'click' event handler
        .on('tooltipopen', function(e) {
            var self = this, // this refers to the element that the tooltip is attached to
                $tooltip = $('#' + this.getAttribute('aria-describedby')); // we can get a reference to the tooltip via the `aria-describedby` attribute

            // bind a click handler to close the tooltip
            $tooltip.on('click', function() {
                $(self).tooltip('close');
            });
        });
});
```

- [Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/77s3mn3t/2/)
- [jQuery UI Tooltip API](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Comment: Your solution works! However, what do you think about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37079191/3345644)? it looks simplier without obtaining the tooltip via node attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.first').on('mouseout focusout', function(event) {
         event.stopImmediatePropagation()
       })
       .tooltip({ content: 'Click to close', position: { my: 'left center', at: 'right center' }, items: '*' }).tooltip('open');

      $( "body" ).delegate( ".ui-tooltip", "click", function() {
            $('.first').tooltip('close');
       });
  });
```

See fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8620jac4/7/)

Comment: Thank you! However this code would work only one time before the tooltip gets closed for the first time ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexandrAbakumov/wszLmqad/1/)), because we need to rebind the `click` handler every time the tooltip shows up.

Comment: Please see updated code and fiddle. I have fixed that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Alexes answer if you wanted to close only on hitting "X":

```
    $(".t1").tooltip({
        content: "<div><div class='tit'>Some super titlet</div> <div class='x'>x</div><div class='con'>Some content super super long</div></h1>",
        disabled: true,
        width:550,
        tooltipClass: "myClass",
          open: function (event, ui) {
            var $element = $(event.target);
            ui.tooltip.each(function () {
                    $("div.x",this).click(function () {
                 $element.tooltip('close');
            });


            });
          },

    }).on('mouseout focusout', function(event) {
                        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    }); 


    $(".tooltip").click(function() {  
            $(this)
            .tooltip("open")

    });
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/analienx/h639vzaw/73/